# PyCrypto is throwing an Invalid Syntax Error when I import pysftp

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko, pycrypto, dsa, pysftp

I am making an SFTP application that connects to my schools server where I have to upload my Python Programs to for class. After adding `pysftp`, `pycrypto` and `paramiko` to the Python 3.5 Library I tried importing the `pysftp` module only to get an Invalid Syntax Error from a line in PyCrypto's `DSA.py` file. The error is being raised on this line `if pow(2,159L) < q < pow(2,160L):` on the "L" value in the `class error(Exception):` class. I tried researching to find a solution or to see if someone else experienced this issue but was unable to find anything. Has anyone else experienced the Syntax Error when importing pysftp on Python 3.5.1. If so how can I resolve this issue? Any insight on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

for python 3x, use the following code for making an sftp application:

```
from ftplib import FTP
```